# Close form after set time

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer

The code below allows me to fade in and out when it opens and closes, which is what I want. However, I would like my form to remain open for 10 seconds before the fading starts.  I am struggling to get that part done.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Public Class frmDefinitions

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                    Handles Button1.Click
        tmr_out.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmDefinitions_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
                    Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Opacity = 100
        tmr_in.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmr_in_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                    Handles tmr_in.Tick
        Me.Opacity += 0.05
        If Me.Opacity = 1 Then
            tmr_in.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmr_out_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                    Handles tmr_out.Tick
        Me.Opacity -= 0.05
        If Me.Opacity = 0 Then
            tmr_out.Enabled = False
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Did u try using a timer? and the event handler for the timer tick would start your fading process.

Comment: I tried using a timer for both, but I had no success. I must have been doing it wrong, it still fade it out after loading.

Comment: Why are you setting initial opacity to 100 in Load, if you wan't to fade the form in? Shouldn't the initial value be 0 for opacity?

Comment: The two timers start both disabled right? In the Form_Load the initial opacity value should be zero not 100 to have the form fade-in. To get the fade-out wait 10 seconds then put a Thread.Sleep(10000) in the button click before the start of the tmr_out

Comment: Are you wanting to delay 10 seconds after the Form is shown or wanting a 10 second delay after the button is clicked.

Comment: @MarkHall I want to wait 10 seconds after the form is shown

Comment: Why on Earth do *you* want to wait 10 seconds.  The user never does, him waiting for 10 seconds while he's fruitlessly banging the Close button is just awful UI.  This makes no sense whatsoever until you explain your motives.  Look, it's pretty! is not a motive, that last 3 times, at most.

Comment: @HansPassant. The 10 second wait is not after the user clicks the close botton. If the user clicks the botton, the form closes right away. The 10 second (which can be incremented depending on user feedback) is for the form to close automatically if the user does not close it.

Comment: Is this some sort of rat maze program?  If you don't get to the end in 10 seconds then you get an electrical shock.  Bzzz!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to setup a third `Timer` to delay the start of your tmr_out `Timer`.  I would trigger the delay as soon as your tmr_in is disabled. You should then get your 10 second delay before you start your fade out. You could also try to use the Form's `Shown` event to start the Delay but you would need to adjust the 10 seconds to accommodate the fade in delay.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim tmrDelay As New Timer()

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        tmrDelay.Interval = 10000
        AddHandler tmrDelay.Tick, AddressOf tmrDelay_Tick
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.Opacity = 0
        tmr_in.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrDelay_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        tmrDelay.Stop()
        tmr_out.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmr_in_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmr_in.Tick
        Me.Opacity += 0.05
        If Me.Opacity = 1 Then
            tmr_in.Enabled = False
            tmrDelay.Start()  'Start Your 10 second delay here.
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmr_out_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmr_out.Tick
        Me.Opacity -= 0.05
        If Me.Opacity = 0 Then
            tmr_out.Enabled = False
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```